# SSO Integration (As Identity Provider)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I need some guidance on my SSO implementation. We have a web application where we are authenticating the user through applications Database. We check user details in USER table and match password. If everything looks good we create PHP session and allow user to Login. One of our partners is requested for SSO integration, they want us to behave like Identity Provider (their application will be Service Provider). I have no idea from where should I start. Few initial guiding points will be a great help.

Thank you!

Comment: Look into https://simplesamlphp.org/

Answer (score 3):

First question is what protocol they want to use:

SAML 2.0, WS-Federation or OpenID Connect / OAuth?

What platforms do you use? - Windows , Linux? Microsoft shop?

Do you want to pay for a commercial product or use open source?

What repository do you want to authenticate against? You mention a DB. Is this SQL Server, MySQL or what? Not all products authenticate against all repositories.

If e.g. the answer is SAML 2.0 and open source, look at shibboleth or simpleSAMLphp.

identityserver would be another possibility.

If the answer is WS-Fed, Microsoft commercial, look at ADFS.